# WordPress - restore original WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I've got post type called "Portfolio" and single-portfolio.php file to handle it (it's WordPress). When I use there something like that it works like expected:

```
$post_id = $post->ID; //returns ID of current portfolio post. Good!
```

BUT when I post short query like this in the middle:

```
$post_id = $post->ID; //returns ID of current portfolio post. Good!
wp_reset_query();
query_posts('posts_per_page=4');
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            the_id(); //returns ID of standard blog post
        endwhile;
    endif; 
wp_reset_query();
$post_id = $post->ID; //returns ID of last BLOG post. Wrong!
```

I'm only concerned about `$post_id` variable in above example. I want it to always return correct ID of current PORTFOLIO post and not be dependent on other queries. How do I achieve that?

Comment: I found a way to do it with $temp = $post; and $post = $temp; after the query but I don't think that it's official and recommended way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`wp_reset_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) function does reset the global `$post` variable as well, but only based on the global `$wp_query` variable. That still is modified, probably due to one of the little flaws in Wordpress. In your case I'd say a simple `WP_Query::rewind_posts()` should do it:

```
wp_reset_query();
$wp_query->rewind_posts();
$post_id = $post->ID;
```

Also you should consider to create a second loop, not overwrite the first one.

See as well:

- [Wordpress wp_reset_query() does not go back to last query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932116/wordpress-wp-reset-query-doesnt-go-back-to-last-query)

Answer (score 4):

I believe [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) will give you the result you are looking for.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=4' );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        // output
    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

I should note that there is another approach which I have [documented in another question asking about what is the difference and when each should be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866154/wordpress-different-wp-query-usage-which-is-correct-in-which-context).