# WordPress: different WP_Query usage: Which is correct, in which context?

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have been creating custom WordPress loops with two different approaches, both which involve creating a new instance of the `WP_Query` object. I typically have multiple loops on a single page.

I do not understand how these two approaches differ, and which is the correct context to use each.

Approach 1: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        // output
    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Approach 2: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata

```
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        // output
    endwhile;
endif;

$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $original_query;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Both appear to yield the same results, however when I turn on `WP_DEBUG`, I see errors with the second approach such as:

> Notice: is_singular was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run.

My questions are these:

- when should I use the `$original_query = $wp_query;` approach?
- what is the relevance of storing and restoring `$wp_query`?
- why does is return the error message when I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some core functions-- some pagination ones, for example ([here is an example where this seems to have been a factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863366/wordpress-only-displaying-2-pages-maximum-for-pagination-when-there-should-be-8))-- assume the `$wp_query` value. If that isn't set those functions don't work. You can cheat around this by saving the original `$wp_query`, running the custom loop, and putting `$wp_query` back. I would argue that this is rarely the best way to do it, and that if you do think you need to do this chances are you should be using `pre_get_posts`, or other filters, to alter the main query itself instead of making a new query. I won't swear that there absolutely are no cases where this would be appropriate, but I do think there is usually a better way.

Your code does not trigger any notices when I try it but if you did something like this it would:

```
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
if (is_single()) {
  echo 'single post';
}
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 5) );
```

Function like `is_single`, `is_archive`, etc. rely on the global `$wp_query` object, which has been unset. I expect it is in cases like that  where you see the notices.

Most everything you need for reference is in http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/query.php and http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/post-template.php

Comment: Thanks for this. I will do some homework on `pre_get_posts`. I defintely don't have `is_single()` inside a code block like your example, so I'm still stumped about the notice. It doesn't help that the message output references the function which generates the message itself, rather than the location of the offending condition.

Comment: There are a number of tags like `is_single` that depend on the `$wp_query` object.

Comment: Is it possible to use `pre_get_posts` in conjunction with the `is_page()` or `is_page_template()` conditions? Or does `pre_get_posts` run before these conditions can be met? I have been trying, without success, to create a custom query for a `page-custom.php` using `pre_get_posts`. I can only make it work with `new WP_Query`, however since it is the only query on that page, my recent reading tells me this is not best practice.