# Wordpress conditional query tag error

Tags: php, wordpress

I've inherited a WordPress site and I am seeing this error in multiple places and I just cannot understand what could be wrong.  Can anyone possibly point me in the right direction please?  Most grateful to you for any rough pointers.

```
Notice: is_author was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before
the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in 
WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.) in
/var/www/clients/client3/web11/web/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2959
```

The previous developer appears to be setting a previous wp_query to null before initiating a new one and WordPress doesn't seem to like this.  These are the lines causing the bug:

```
$original_wp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;

$arguments = array('showposts' => 3, 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'page', 'order' => 'ASC');
$wp_query = new WP_Query($arguments);
```

If I remove the lines:

```
$original_wp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
```

Then the bug disappears but I'm reluctant to do this as it appears a pretty conscious decision to set the query to null.  I'm wondering 1.  Why the developer would do this?  and 2.  Is it good / bad practice?  3. Removing the lines causes the bug to disappear but maybe there is something better I should do?

Hugely grateful to you for your help.

Comment: Well please include the relevant code, apparently being in your functions.php around line 2959

Comment: The previous developer appears to have added these lines before a "while" statement:

Comment: @kraftner check the error.  "wp-includes/functions.php".

Comment: Many thanks for considering my problem.  I have edited the question a bit.  Also taking a look at functions.php

Comment: @PieterGoosen I see this, but this still only left me guessing what the actual problem is.

Comment: Please add some more code. The question is if this is called inside some hook or is just directly inside functions.php.

Comment: @PieterGoosen There is no need to check Wordpress core files.

Comment: All functions.php tells me is "Marks something as being incorrectly called."  with no more information

Comment: All functions.php tells me is "Marks something as being incorrectly called."  with no more information.  @kraftner Thanks, the code is not called inside functions.php so it is in a separate template file.  The snippet I have added is all the code that is causing the error.  It's a bit weird.

Comment: Yes, I know that, just wanted to make kraftner alert that he was sending Euan on a wild goose chase

Comment: @PieterGoosen Oh sorry, I was reading too fast, just saw functions.php and visually skipped "wp-includes".

Comment: No problem.  Apparently the developer is trying to do some kind of custom loop by switching the wp_query variable, performing the while and then switching it back.  This is causing the bug.  I wonder why they are doing this.  There must be a reason.

Comment: Aha!  Found this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866154/wordpress-different-wp-query-usage-which-is-correct-in-which-context

Comment: this is exactly my problem

Comment: try use <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> to reset a query (instead of ='null')

Comment: Thanks everyone.  wp_reset_query was already there so I think that the $original_query = $wp_query, $wp_query=null stuff was just bad practice.  My issue appears to be solved.